# How to check if it is a subset with linked lists in C

Tags: c

Good day everyone! This is my First time posting in Stack Overflow and I am quite enjoying my stay here.

So this function will return TRUE if the linked list A is a subset of linked list B.

But it seems that it only changes the boolean value if it is done checking the first node. How do I make it check all of it? The lists are in proper order.

```
    boolean compareList(LIST A, LIST B)
{
    LIST p, q;
    boolean checker=FALSE;
    for(p=A;p!=NULL;p=p->next){
        for(q=B;q!=NULL;q=q->next){
            if(q->data==p->data){
                checker=TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return checker;
}
```

And this is the structure datatype:

```
    typedef struct node{
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}*List;
```

Thank you and have a good day, Stack Overflow!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oops, edited the body. Thank you

Comment: Can you assume the common elements are in the same order in both lists?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that. But what if it is not in the proper order?

Comment: If they're not in the same order, then you may return false even if all of A is in B (but in a different order).  But requiring the order to be the same does make sense, since in that sense A is truly a sublist of B.

Comment: Ok, so can there be gaps in B?  For instance, if A is (1, 2, 3) and B is (10, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13), does that count as A being a subset?

Comment: So that means that I should arrange the both lists in the same order?

Comment: I asked a specific question.  A is (1, 2, 3) and B is (10, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13).  Do you want TRUE or FALSE?  It sounds like you haven't yet figured out what functionality you want?

Comment: The problem statement is very, very incomplete, and OP doesn't seem to be able to answer very specific questions about the desired functionality.  Voting to close on the grounds that it's unclear what's being asked.

Comment: @TomKarzes - Please reconsider.  I actually think you were helping him flesh out some of the issues.  Maybe the initial problem definition wasn't well defined.

Comment: @Jim I agree, but then OP stopped responding altogether.  The question was posted prematurely and cannot be answered because OP doesn't know what he wants it to do.  I'd be happy help by asking questions that will pinpoint it, and in fact I already have, but they have gone unanswered.  So it's a dead thread.  If OP responds later, and edits the post to clarify it, then I'll retract it.

Comment: @TomKarzes Fair enough.

Comment: @Robert - Please re-submit your question.  You'll need to address the issues Tom raised and make a decision on the whether the lists are ordered or not.

Comment: @Jim It's too late.  OP has stopped reading comments and in fact has accepted an answer that has bugs which I explained very clearly in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each element of A you have to test if it is present in B. If ever only one element of A is not in B, just return FALSE.
Your code needed only a few modifications:

```
boolean compareList(LIST A, LIST B)
{
    LIST p, q;

    for(p=A;p!=NULL;p=p->next){
        for(q=B;q!=NULL;q=q->next){
            if(q->data==p->data)
                break; // The element is found, no need to go further in B
        }
        if (q == NULL) // At least one element of A is not in B
            return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Note: in your code you use `->data` as a member of `LIST`. Your struct typedef is named `List` and has no `data` member :)

Comment: This disregards order, which it sounded like OP cared about (although OP doesn't seem to understand the problem).  But this answer will fail if A contains duplicates that are not duplicated in B.  Example:  A is (1, 2, 2, 3) and B is (1, 2, 3).  I would not consider A to be a subset of B in this case.  But the problem statement is very incomplete so it's not clear what OP wants.  That's why no answer is really possible for now.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list `A` will be a subset of `B` if, as you loop through the list B, you will find the address A somewhere within. Once the address `A` is found, the rest of the lists will be identical. So, you only need to search in one loop for this address `A`

It is better to compare pointers rather than data as data of two nodes can be same, but the addresses will be different.

Code is below.

```
boolean compareList(LIST A, LIST B)
{
  LIST p;
  boolean checker=FALSE;
  for(p=B;p!=NULL;p=p->next)
  {
    if (p == A)
    {
      checker = TRUE;
      break;
    }
  }

  return checker;
}
```

In response to Tom's comments --

Consider

```
List B -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> B4 -> B5 -> B6 -> ...
list A -> A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> ..
```

Now if,

```
A == B3, then it follows that,
A1 == B4,
A2 == B5 and so on..
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  It needs to check the list values.  You can't assume that the nodes are shared.

Comment: if the address `A` is found in list `B` the rest of the members have to be shared until NULL.

Comment: Yes, but if it's not then you'll report a false failure.  All this is doing is checking if A is a shared tail of B.  Different problem.

Comment: Is there any way that A can be a subset without being a shared tail?

Comment: Of course.  Here's a very clear example.  A is (1, 2, 3) and B is (10, 1, 2, 3, 11)  A is a subset B.  They share no nodes.  In fact, B could simply be a copy of A and your solution would still fail.